# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif', multiple elseif

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

Here is my code :

```
<?php
   if ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<85 AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/A.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=85 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<115  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/B.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=115 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<145  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/C.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=145 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<175  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/D.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=175 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<205  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/E.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=205 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<235  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/F.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=235  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/G.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
    <?php } ?>
```

that return me this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF), expecting end of file

where my syntax is wrong?

Comment: Why do you close the `}` and then reopen for the `elseif`? That just makes it harder to read.

Comment: Use 1 conditional and assign a variable to `$data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]` based on the condition, then just use the HTML once.

Comment: @u_mulder I don't think this problem has been added to that list. Should we reopen this?

Comment: You are using the associative index like constants, this is bad, use quotes: `$data[0]['energy']['name']`

Comment: the answers of @Praveen Kumar is the good solution, thx for the help !

Comment: @AbraCadaver I don't think this problem has been added to that list. Should we reopen this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, you don't break the PHP parser before `elseif` or `else`. It's similar to having an `echo` in between them, which makes it a Syntax Error. Use this way:

```
<?php
  if ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<85 AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/A.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=85 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<115  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/B.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=115 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<145  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/C.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=145 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<175  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/D.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=175 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<205  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/E.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=205 AND $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]<235  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/F.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } elseif ($data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]>=235  AND $data[0][energy][name] == "Diesel") { ?>
    <h5 class="text-light">Emission de cO2 : <?php echo $data[0][extraUrbanKmConsumption]; ?> <img src="icone c02/G.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></h5>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Working, thx ...

Comment: Euugh - I literally had to copy/paste both chunks of code into Notepad++ to see what the difference was; this code isn't the easiest on the eyes :P

Comment: @CD001 I did inform in the beginning, not to break the PHP code. `:)` Didn't you notice it? `:)` *Wait. Are you using Notepad++? Ewww... :(*

Comment: Yes  sorry for the bad copy/paste !

Comment: Yeah - I saw the explanation but I couldn't see the wood for the trees (to coin a phrase) in the code ... it's like staring at the code in The Matrix. You totally deserve the +1 for making sense of the original code without going cross-eyed ;) Heh yeah, I use NP++ as a quick scratchpad for syntax highlighting.

Comment: @CD001 I used PHPFormatter... `:P` He he...

Comment: @CD001 I use Sublime Text ♥

Comment: Its done , sorry  !